# Return multiple arrays using "map" function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming, reduce

My code has an array of elements as follows:

```
element: { fromX: { id: ... } , toX: { id: ... } }
```

Requirement is  to pull all the `fromX` ids into one array, and all `toX` ids into other.

There are a couple of different ways,
such as using `foreach`, `reduce`, iterating for each respectively, but I'm searching for an optimal functional way to return two arrays with one mapping?

Comment: do you have only two properties in an object?

Comment: Can you provide a more thorough input and output? Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect to get? An array that contains two arrays with the mapped values?

Comment: Can you expand the example code a bit more to show the full structure? I.e., what does it look like when multiple `fromX` and `fromY` values are shown?

Comment: `[froms, tos] = transpose(elements.map(e => [e.fromX, e.toX]))` is the functional way - unfortunately there is no native `transpose` function in JS

Answer (score 11):

Using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const data=[{fromX:{id:1},toX:{id:2}},{fromX:{id:3},toX:{id:4}},{fromX:{id:5},toX:{id:6}},{fromX:{id:7},toX:{id:8}}]

const [fromX,toX] = data.reduce(([a,b], {fromX,toX})=>{
  a.push(fromX.id);
  b.push(toX.id);
  return [a,b];
}, [[],[]]);

console.log(fromX);
console.log(toX);
```

Comment: Very very elegant!

Answer (score 2):

You could take an array for the wanted keys and map the value. Later take a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for getting single `id`.

```js
const
    transpose = array => array.reduce((r, a) => a.map((v, i) => [...(r[i] || []), v]), []),
    array = [{ fromX: { id: 1 }, toX: { id: 2 } }, { fromX: { id: 3 }, toX: { id: 4 } }],
    keys = ['fromX', 'toX'],
    [fromX, toX] = transpose(array.map(o => keys.map(k => o[k].id)));

console.log(fromX);
console.log(toX);
```

Comment: I believe your answer is not respecting one requirements of the question "I would like to pull all the fromX ids into one array, and all toX ids into other.".

Comment: @thibpat, please see `fromX` and `toX`.

Comment: When running your snippet, I get: `fromX = [1,2]` and `toX = [3,4]`. I believe the expected result is `fromX = [1, 3]` and `toX = [2, 4]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const arr = [{
  fromX: {
    id: 1
  },
  toX: {
    id: 2
  }
}, {
  fromX: {
    id: 3
  },
  toX: {
    id: 4
  }
}]
let {
  arr1,
  arr2
} = arr.reduce((acc, {
  fromX,
  toX
}) => ({ ...acc,
  arr1: [...acc.arr1, fromX],
  arr2: [...acc.arr2, toX]
}), {
  arr1: [],
  arr2: []
})
console.log(arr1, arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using below solution

```js
var array = [{ fromX: { id: 1 }, toX: { id: 2 } }, { fromX: { id: 3 }, toX: { id: 4 } }], 
 arrayX = array.map(x => x.fromX), arraytoX = array.map(toX => toX.toX)

console.log(arrayX);
console.log(arraytoX );
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning multiple keys from the list requires using maps in jQuery.

```
var list = [{ name:"h1",emailId:"h1@h1.com",password:"h1"},{ name:"h2",emailId:"h2@h2.com",password:"h2"},name:"h3",emailId:"h3@h3.com",password:"h3"}]
```

Obtain only the name and emailId from this list. Subsequently, use the map keyword.

```
var filter = list.map(x => ({name : x.name, email : x.emailId }));
```